# import Excel data into MS Access tables

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010

I have an Excel sheet which is generated by a program like this:
[image]

I want to import that sheet into MS Access program. How to get those data into related table by filtering data?

|DeptNo|DeptName| =>(dept table)

|StaffNo|StaffName| =>(staff table)

|DeptNo|StaffNo|WorkDate|Week| =>(attendance table)

Comment: You will need to work on the excel file and 'clean' it manually so it can go into MS Access. You could record a macro of the cleaning process so you can do it faster.

Comment: I don't understand the data row  StaffSummary = 803, which certainly doesn't seem to add up.

Comment: that  feild is not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might write a program outlined as --

```
Revised on 3/25 late
Dim WeAreInWorkDates As String

For each row in worksheet

    If ColA.value = Dept row then
        WeAreInWorkDates = "NO"  'reset flag to false
        get values
        if these values don't already exist in DeptTable then
            Insert new row into DeptTable
        endif

    elseIf ColA.value = Staff row then
        WeAreInWorkDates = "NO"  'reset flag to false
        get values
        if these values don't already exist in StaffTable then
            Insert new row into StaffTable
        endif

    elseIf ColA.value = "WorkDate"
        bypass row
        WeAreInWorkDates = "YES"   ' set flag

     elseIf ColA.value = "Summary"
        bypass row
        WeAreInWorkDates = "NO"  'reset flag to false

     elseIf ColA.value = blanks
        bypass row

     elseIf  WeAreInWorkDates = "YES" then        
        'get values from the row into local variables
        Dim xxx
        xxx = myXLS.Cells(nRow,nCol)  ...  etc
        ' Prevent double posting of the XLS into the MDB tables
        'if these values don't exist in AttendanceTable then
        SET rst = db(Select * From AttendanceTable Where atKey = xxx(i.e. myLocalVars))
        if rst.BOF and rst.EOF then    ' rst is empty, ergo not yet posted
            Insert row in AttendanceTable
        endif

     else
         display that we have an unknown row
     endif
```

Comment: thanks this the way what i want. but i'm poor in vba . i will try to understand.if you can please provide actual code for  the part "elseIf  WeAreInWorkDates        
    get values
    if these values don't exist in AttendanceTable then
        Insert row in AttendanceTable" then i can handle other part myself.

Comment: can i named the range between work date and staff summery like.range("work date","staffsummery") or another then it canbe use for import to access rather than one by one.

Comment: I have revised the above.  WeAreInWorkDates is a variable that tracks whether we are between WorkDates and Summary because the actual attendance rows do not have a line identifier.  You don't want to do the Range approach, but rather test each line for prior posting to the mdb and prevent double posting.  If you just slammed in the range then some operator error could double post the same XLS twice (or thrice)...